# Angular throws an error even though my application works

Tags: angular

I made a pipeline that filters through data. This works perfectly, but the strange thing is, I get en error. Why?

Here is the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at FilterPipe.push../src/app/filter.pipe.ts.FilterPipe.transform (main.js:248)
    at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (vendor.js:84259)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js:84828)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:84786)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.js:85420)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.js:85380)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/MembersComponent.ngfactory.js:122)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.js:85372)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js:84768)
    at callViewAction (vendor.js:85009)
```

In the error it says it can't read the property 'filter'. 'filter' is the name of my pipeline:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(werte: any, kriterium: any ): any {
    if (kriterium === undefined) {
      return werte;
    }
    return werte.filter((member: { memberName: { toLowerCase: () => { includes: (arg0: any) => void; }; }; }) => {
      return member.memberName.toLowerCase().includes(kriterium.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

In the html file I also don't get any errors:

```
<div *ngFor="let member of MEMBERS | filter:memberFilter">
  <div>{{member.memberName}}</div>
  <div>{{member.memberRank}}</div>
  <div>{{member.memberBeschreibung}}</div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Here I call the service for the data:

```
export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {

  MEMBERS: MembersInterface[];

  memberFilter = '';

  constructor(private memberService: MemberServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.memberService.getMembers().subscribe(member => {
      this.MEMBERS = member;
    });
  }

}
```

Why is Angular throwing an error even though my application works as it should?

Comment: Seems like you are adding data to werte later in the lifecycle. It is undefined initially and then it gets the data. Hence, the werte.filter is throwing the error once.

Comment: Where do you define and populate `MEMBERS`? Presumably it's undefined the first time your filter is called.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I added this to the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MEMBERS: MembersInterface[];
```

MEMBERS is initially undefined. So ngFor breaks because it doesn't get any iterable value till you get members.

You can either assign MEMBERS a default value, i.e., empty array:

```
MEMBERS: MembersInterface[] = [];
```

Or,

wrap your template with ngIf like this:-

```
<ng-container *ngIf="MEMBERS"> // will be true only if MEMBERS has some value other than undefined/empty/false
<div *ngFor="let member of MEMBERS | filter:memberFilter">
  <div>{{member.memberName}}</div>
  <div>{{member.memberRank}}</div>
  <div>{{member.memberBeschreibung}}</div>
  <hr>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

**EDIT**:  Thanks to [John Montgomery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7496073/john-montgomery) for suggesting a better approach ([ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngcontainer)) than span.

Comment: If you're going to do it the second way, you should use `ng-container` instead of `span` since it doesn't add anything to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getMembers` function is presumably asynchronous, so the first time your filter runs `MEMBERS` is still undefined because the function hasn't completed yet. Then when you get to `return werte.filter` in your filter, you get your error. But later after the function completes, it does have a value which is why your program still works.

The simplest solution would be to just initialize it with an empty array:

```js
export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {

  MEMBERS: MembersInterface[] = [];
```

Then it will always have a value, so you shouldn't get that error.